# How do I implement map click events in r leaflet and reset the events to default?

Tags: r, shiny-reactivity, r-leaflet

I want to implement two map click events in my map, map_marker_click, and map_click. When I click on a marker on the map(using map_marker_click), I want the event to filter other related charts based on the id of the clicked marker. Using the map_click event by clicking the base map, I want the event to reset the map and graphs to default (with all the markers and charts).
With my current code, I can only be able to click on a marker and only that marker is displayed on the map with the corresponding chart.
Here is my code:

```
 #reactive event for map click
  map_click<-reactive({
    clk=input$maps2_marker_click
    if(is.null(clk$id)){
       return(final_data)   
    }
      else{
        rev_filter<-final_data %>% filter(Kiosk_Id_number==clk$id)
        return(rev_filter)
            }
  }
  )


   #color function for waterpoint types
  pal=colorFactor(c("sienna2","green3","cornflowerblue"),domain = final_data$Water_point_type)

  #interactive map with click event
  output$maps2<-renderLeaflet(
    leaflet() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        data = map_click(),
        fillColor = ~pal(Water_point_type),
        fillOpacity = 1.0,
        radius = 8,
        stroke = FALSE,
        lat = ~latitude,
        lng = ~longitude,
        layerId = ~Kiosk_Id_number
  ) #end renderleaflet


  #facet plots 
  #plots are filtered based on the map click
  output$facet_plot<-renderPlotly(
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(map_click(),aes(x=Day,y=Daily_revenue,group=Kiosk_Id_number))+
        geom_col(aes(fill=Water_point_type))+
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("sienna2","cornflowerblue")
        )+
        geom_line(aes(y=Daily_Average),linetype="dashed", size=0.4,color="gray0")+
        facet_wrap(~Kiosk_Id_number,scales = "free_y",ncol = 2)+
        labs(
          y="Daily Average Revenue (GHC)")+
        scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("05-Jun-19","31-Jul-19",
                                  "27-Sep-19","28-Nov-19","31-Dec-19",
                                  "31-Jan-20","28-Feb-20","26-Mar-20"))+
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks)+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,size = 7),
              axis.title = element_text(size=9),
              axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
              axis.title.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size=6,face="bold"),
              strip.text = element_text(face="bold"),
              strip.background = element_blank(),
              strip.text.x = element_text(face="bold.italic",colour ="gray0",size=8,margin=margin(0,0,0,0,"cm")),
              legend.title = element_blank(),
              #legend.position = "bottom",
              panel.grid = element_blank(),
              panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines")       
        )  
    ) 
  )#end renderplot
```